# In jqGrid, how can I call a method after subGridRowColapsed completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with subgrids and I'm looking for a way to call a method after I collapse a subgrid.  Right now I have:

```
subGridRowColapsed: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
    position_slider();
}
```

My position_slider() method uses the grid height to reposition a slider element.  The problem is that this is being called before the subgrid is actually collapsed, so the height of the grid has not yet been updated.  How can I call this method *after* the subgrid is collapsed?  I thought about using a short timeout, but that might not be reliable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  In the subGridRowColapsed, I trigger a reload of the grid and then in my gridComplete I call the function I wanted to be called after the subgrid was collapsed:

```
...
gridComplete: function () {
    position_slider();
},
...
subGridRowColapsed: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
    $('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");
}
...
```

Hopefully this helps anyone looking to do something similar.

Comment: I actually discovered an issue with this approach.  If you have more than one subgrid open, the reloadGrid will collapse them all, which may not be the desired behavior.